# How to set tableView cell title in ios?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am parsing JSON and storing it in an array.I have a custom cell subclass in which I am trying to set the title of a label from the content of parsed JSON.
This is the parsing process.

```
@implementation BlogScreenViewController    
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
  self.jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 NSError *error = nil;
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:web_services/blog.php"];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 self.jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
 for (NSDictionary *obj in self.jsonArray)    
{
    NSLog(@"JSON string output :- %@ ", [obj objectForKey:@"titre"]); // shows titles
}
```

In custom cell subclass

```
    // set blog title label
    UILabel *blogTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 20, 200, 20)];
   // blogTitleLabel.text = @"This is blog title";  // This shows properly if used. 

    for (NSDictionary *obj in blogScreenVC.jsonArray ) //This doesn't work.
    {
         blogTitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj objectForKey:@"titre"]];
    }
    [blogTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:9]];
    [self addSubview:blogTitleLabel];
```

Comment: what issue you are facing in this..

Comment: place your question clearly? Your question title talk about tableview title. But in your question body tell about cell's name? text some description clearly.

Comment: Give the custom cell label obj as property synthesize in custom cell class use that obj in your table view delegate methods.

Comment: @Romance - any sample code please for your approach?

Comment: Why you are setting text on label in `customcell` class instead of `cellForRowAtIndex` method?

Comment: You're using custom cell then why did you add label via programmatically? some confusion here. Refer this link to learn about how to create custom cell. http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: These lines you have to do custom cell .@interface FeedCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitile;                After Property synthesize you can  use this customclass in any viewcontroller, in that tableview delegate methods like below code            - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
cell.lblTitile.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayforlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"ProductName"]];

Comment: cell.textLabel.text =[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];...this has four strings @"1" , @"2"..etc....but there are other labels also...

Comment: @icodes i provioded the code if you are not understanding i will give answer to your question

Comment: Okay I tried this... for (NSDictionary *obj in self.jsonArray )
     {
        cell.blogTitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",     [obj objectForKey:@"titre"]];
    }
Shows one title only from array...However NSLog of array shows more

Comment: @icodes see the below answer which is answered by the dilep.It will solve your problem follow the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Setting lebel.text in customcell class add it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Create Property of label in `customcell.h` file

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

And in `customcell.m` file synthesys it.

```
@synthesize label = _label;
```

And in you `viewcontroller.m` file

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell"; 

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 

    if (self.jsonArray.count !=0) {
      NSMutableDictionary * tmpDictn = [self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      if ([tmpDictn objectForKey:@"titre"] != nil)
        {
          cell.label.text = [tmpDictn objectForKey:@"titre"];
        }else{
          cell.label.text = @"tmpDictn does not contain data";
        }
    }else{
          cell.label.text = @"jsonArray does not contain data";
    }

    return cell;
}
```